# Should I provide my transcripts for all years or only the last year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-kingdom, transcript-of-records

I am applying for a a PhD in the UK, and they ask for my bachelor transcript. Should I only include the third year transcripts or full three years ? Since I am translating it from another language it is better for me to only include the last year

Answer (score 13):

This may vary by university, but a transcript is a full academic record of your time at an institution. As such, they will expect information on every course that you took, all three years. A partial transcript is obviously acceptable for degrees which have not yet been completed, but omitting completed courses may look like you have something to hide.

There will likely be a firm requirement to provide a full original transcript, and if not in English, an authorised translation, before your place is confirmed, regardless of whether a partial transcript is acceptable for an offer to be given.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and clear answer is YES. Include all year's transcripts. This is especially important in the UK, where the final marks are more crude than other places (e.g., 70% and up is concerned to be A).

Also, many colleges in the UK might have independent offices for initial evaluation of your application, and they would require all transcripts.

In case of doubt just ask the relevant supervisor/faculty. This is a crucial point to understand.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating applicants for PhD studies, the reader of your application will check whether you seem to have a good chance of finishing the degree within the suggested time span. This is especially important in the UK, where the duration of PhD studies if relatively fixed.

Now for checking whether you have a good chance of finishing in time, they need to see what courses you took in the past. In some fields, there are considerable differences between universities (and countries of study), especially regarding whether the focus is more on the theoretical or more applied topics. Thus, the full transcript allows them to estimate whether you bring the needed background knowledge with you for the PhD program that you are applying to, as they want to avoid that you have to spend time on filling your gaps in knowledge before your can work on research in a productive way.

**As a summary, full transcripts are essential for a good application!** Even if you can - for some reason - only provide a partial translation, if your certificates are good enough for, say, Google translate to extract some of their meaning, it makes sense to include scans/copies of the original non-English transcript. This holds especially for languages such as Spanish or Italian, which are close enough to English for a rough translation.